# @font-face not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, font-face

I'm attempting a custom font and have utilized everything I know of (including ?#iefix) and it's working great on every browser except IE8 and IE7. I simplified it down to bare bones and still see the issue.

[Here's a link to the live version of the test](http://berinti.com/compass-learning/test/)

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>This is a test.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Here:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'swz721kc';
    src: url('fonts/swz721kc.eot');
    src: url('fonts/swz721kc.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/swz721kc.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/swz721kc.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/swz721kc.svg#swz721kc') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'swz721kc';
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'swz721kc';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(/compass-learning/test/fonts/swz721kc.eot);
  src: local('swz721kc'),
    url(/compass-learning/test/fonts/swz721kc.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

This is the format I have used to embed our fonts and have them work across browsers.

Comment: @cathius - Did you make sure to push the **reload button** on your IE browser environment so that the stylesheet was reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

@font-face {

```
font-family: 'swz721kc';
src: url('/fonts/swz721kc.eot');
src: url('/fonts/swz721kc.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/swz721kc.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/swz721kc.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/swz721kc.svg#swz721kc') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

"/" is added before "fonts".